# Routing Engine Using OpenStreetMap Data

Tags: math, graph, routes, mapping, openstreetmap

As part of my academic project, I have to build a routing engine based on data supplied from OSM. I have looked at the data model of OSM and I'm all fine with it. However, I'm having trouble converting an OSM XML file into a graph structure (nodes and edges) that I can use to apply search algorithms (Dijkstra, A* etc.) on. I would like the graph to be stored in memory to allow fast read/write.

So can anyone shed light or suggest techniques on how this can be done, or even provide pointers for further research.

Please note that I'm not allowed to re-use existing routing engines as this would defeat the purpose of doing the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is:

1. create a node for every `<node>` item
2. every `<way>` entry is a sequenced list of `<nd>` items, each of which is a backreference to a node. So for each `<way>`, you iterate pairwise through its `<nd>`s and create an arc between the two nodes referenced.

You can do this in one pass using a streaming XML parser, since the XML data defines all the nodes before the ways.

The data doesn't intrinsically include distances, so you need to calculate that from the latlon of each node. You should also take account of the road type (`highway=*`) and the access info (`access=*`) in your routing, and you probably also want to ignore ways that are not traversable (eg `waterway=stream`) but that's all down to your specific situation.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements